# Using Gate auth to check if a user is a moderator - getting Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I use the `Gate` facade to check if a user is the post owner or the creator of a subreddit before allowing him to edit or even view the edit link on the view.

However, I'm having trouble check if a user is a moderator of a given subreddit. The logged in user has already been placed as a moderator for that subreddit but whenever I visit it, I get the following error

> ErrorException in AuthServiceProvider.php line 18:
>
> Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::Illuminate\Auth{closure}() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\reddit\resources\views\partials\post.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\reddit\resources\views\partials\post.blade.php)

Here are my tables

```
users: id, name, email... 
posts: id, user_id, subreddit_id...
subreddits: id, name, user_id (to designate the owner of the sub)
moderators: id, user_id, subreddit_id...
```

Here's the Gate implemention inside AuthServiceProvider

```
$gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post, $subreddit) {
        // Check if user is subreddit owner
        if ($user->id === $post->subreddit->user->id) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is the post author
        if ($user->id === $post->user_id) {
            return true;
        }
        // this is where I'm having trouble
        if($user->id === $subreddit->moderator->user_id) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
});
```

Then on `post.blade.php` I check if the user has access before showing him the html markup and this is where the page breaks.

```
@can('update-post', $post, $subreddit)
    <a href="{{ action('PostsController@edit', [$post->id]) }}">Edit</a>
@endcan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending multiple arguments, so you need to group them in an array

```
@can('update-post', [$post, $subreddit])
    <a href="{{ action('PostsController@edit', [$post->id]) }}">Edit</a>
@endcan
```

Comment: I think that solved my issue but gave me a new error `Trying to get property of non-object` I guess on `$subreddit->moderator->user_id`

Answer (score 0):

@halnex

It's a bit late to get on the thread, I know, but you would need to provide the blade template with any additional variables (besides user) you use to set the permission with $gate->define. In essence, select the $post and $subreddit you are referring to. The Gate contract does not "know" about those models, just the $user one.